# Null/undefined check in map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have a small angular material table which gets filled by a function

```
this.dataSource.data = data.data.map(item => ({
    id: item._id,
    ticketId: item.key,
    summary: item.fields.summary,
    priority: item.fields.priority.name,
    createdAt: item.fields.created,
    createdBy: item.fields.reporter.emailAddress,
    state: item.fields.status.name
}));
```

But in some of my elements `item.fields.priority.name` or `item.fields.status.name` are null/undefined. Is there a possibility to check for this and than just write sth. like "*not defined*"? I tried with `? item.fields.status.name : 'not defined'` but i still get

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `?.` and `??` operators:

```
priority: item.fields.priority?.name ?? 'this is undefined'
```

Or why not just use `undefined`:

```
priority: item.fields.priority?.name
```

Comment: I feel like voodoo like this keeps being added to JS everyday. So hard to keep up.

Answer (score 2):

this should work fine

```js
this.dataSource.data = data.data.map((item) => ({
  id: item._id,
  ticketId: item.key,
  summary: item.fields?.summary ?? "not defined",
  priority: item.fields?.priority?.name ?? "not defined",
  createdAt: item.fields?.created ?? "not defined",
  createdBy: item.fields?.reporter?.emailAddress ?? "not defined",
  state: item.fields?.status?.name ?? "not defined",
}));
```

**docs**

- [Nullish_coalescing_operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 0):

Nullish coalescing operator and Optional chaining works fine as mentioned in other solutions.

If you want to have some custom logic, you can always process the data and return the map with the object to be added to array.

**Example**

```
this.dataSource.data = data.data.map(item => {
  
  // null check or any other custom logic.
  const priority = item.fields && item.fields.priority && item.fields.priority.name ? item.fields.priority.name : 'not defined'

  return {
    id: item._id,
    ticketId: item.key,
    summary: item.fields.summary,
    priority: priority,
    createdAt: item.fields.created,
    createdBy: item.fields.reporter.emailAddress,
    state: item.fields.status.name
}});
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for this kind of different approach!

Comment: @Sithys This was the approach before Nullish coalescing operator and Optional chaining  was introduced. Still useful to have checks other than null